# Putty ssh client not working after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: putty

i upgrade my ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10, and now, my putty is not working, i click on it, and nothing happen, i tried to reinstall and still the same problem..

Thanks

Comment: So you are trying to connect to your ubuntu machine via putty on windows?

Comment: nop, im using ubuntu,

Comment: Sorry but why do you need putty on an ubuntu machine? What's the usecase for that?

Comment: im just lazy to take not of all servers ip's so, i use putty, to organize all the connections

Comment: You could try 'purging' the package and update/install it again. If you used reinstall it will use the same package that is in your cache so not much might change. You can also run `putty` in your terminal to see what exactly happens.

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling the Xorg options when logging in. 
[enabling Xorg options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYYpB.jpg)